# Run before ALL integration tests

Tags: go, integration-testing, go-testing

Does Go have any ability to run some code before ALL tests? I know that Go provides with TestMain(), but its package scope func, and will set up and tear down only tests in package where she located.

But I want to run some docker test containers before ALL tests, and of course tear it down, when all test be done.

Comment: Not specifically using the Go tools which if that is exactly what you're after ignore this; However you could look into Makefiles which can provide a build script system based on *nix terminal commands. I've previously used this for Integration testing (start containers, run go test, tear-down containers regardless of test result).

Comment: `init()` runs before all tests _in a package_.

Answer (score 3):

Write `Setup()` and `TearDown()` functions in your tests. If you are using table driven tests, or normal tests, call `Setup()` and `TearDown()` in each test before and after.

You can also use a test `suite`, which does a similar thing, it kind of provides this feature like a library:
https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite